# Get parent from its child in object structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object which looks something like this:

```
{
"11": {
    "id": 11,
    "parent_product": 0,
    "product_name": "WebStore",
    "product_price_city": null,
    "child": {
      "12": {
        "id": 12,
        "parent_product": 11,
        "product_name": "WebStore - Single",
        "product_price_city": 500
      },
      "13": {
        "id": 13,
        "parent_product": 11,
        "product_name": "WebStore - Full",
        "product_price_city": 2500
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the key `11` has two childs: `12` and `13`.

In a different object which looks like this:

```
{
  "316": 
    {
      "id": 316,
      "product_id": 13,
      "sold_by": 1,
      "product_price": 5000,
      "subscription_month": 3,
      "updated_by": 0,
      "created_at": 1449573556
    },
  "317":
    {
      "id": 317,
      "product_id": 12,
      "sold_by": 1,
      "product_price": 5000,
      "subscription_month": 3,
      "updated_by": 0,
      "created_at": 1449573556
    }
}
```

I here the product_id is either 12 or 13, that is it will always be a child.

I need to get the parent id of 12 and 13, so I can access they the first object.

```
data.11
```

How can I get it in JavaScript?

Comment: can you change how the data is organized/structured or is this final?

Comment: Each child has one and only one parent?

Comment: @Amir: Yes. Each child will have only one parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the properties and iterate over it.

```js
var object1 = {
        "11": { "id": 11, "parent_product": 0, "product_name": "WebStore", "product_price_city": null, "child": { "12": { "id": 12, "parent_product": 11, "product_name": "WebStore - Single", "product_price_city": 500 },
        "13": { "id": 13, "parent_product": 11, "product_name": "WebStore - Full", "product_price_city": 2500 } } },
        "15": { "id": 15, "parent_product": 0, "product_name": "WebStore", "product_price_city": null, "child": undefined },
        "17": { "id": 17, "parent_product": 0, "product_name": "WebStore", "product_price_city": null }
    },
    key;

function getParent(id, object) {
    var k;
    Object.keys(object).some(function (a) {
        if (object[a].child && id in object[a].child) {
            k = a;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return k;
}

document.write(getParent('12', object1) + '<br>'); // '11'
key = getParent('42', object1);
if (typeof key === 'undefined') {
    document.write('no key found');
}
```

Comment: There's one problem.There are some cases where parent has no child. What should be done in that case?

Comment: add a test in the if clause `if (object[a].child && ...`, like above.